# put the selected filename insted of no file choosen :react js

Tags: reactjs

when ever i choose a file for example image2.jpg i want that no file choosen text to change into the filename

```
<input type="file"onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.allValues.BloodReport} />
```

[image]

full code i have put in codesand box

Comment: You cannot set value programmatically to input with type file => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html#:~:text=The%20only%20way%20to%20set,file%20from%20the%20client's%20computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `value` from `<input  type="file" />` then try !

```
<input
  style={styles.cutumbuttons}
  type="file"
  style={styles.cutumbuttons}
  name="ultraSound"
  // accept="application/pdf"
  onChange={this.onChange}
//value={this.state.allValues.BloodReport}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it without value property. name will be showed automaically.

```
<input type="file"onChange={this.onChange} />
```